# Why do some employers in the United States ask employees to accept the grant when granting them Restricted Stock Units (RSUs)?

Tags: united-states, rsu, signature

Why do some employers in the United States ask employees to accept the grant when granting them Restricted Stock Units (RSUs)?

For example, accepting the grant could be done by clicking on some "Accept" button on the financial institution's website that manages the stock plan. When employers pay the salaries to the employees, they don't ask employees to accept the payment. Why is it different for RSUs?

Answer (score 5):

How would the employer enforce the restrictions in the RSU agreement if the employee didn’t accept the agreement?

For example, many RSU agreements prohibit the employee from hedging the stock position or selling an interest in the future stock to others. Without some sign that the employee accepted these restrictions, how would the employer legally enforce them?

Your salary doesn't come with any restrictions, so there is no need for you to agree to get it.